# Run subprocess.call(cmd) while the cmd is a text variable

Tags: python, unix

In python, is it possible to run a shell command, while the command stored in variable as text ?
for example:

```
  self.command_editor = QTextEditor()
  self.command_editor.append("echo command")
  cmd = str(self.command_editor.toPlainText())
  call(cmd)
```

this code doesn`t work!

Answer (score 1):

this is the right answer:

```
  self.command_editor = QTextEditor()
  self.command_editor.append("echo command")
  cmd = str(self.command_editor.toPlainText())
  call(cmd, shell = True) #the mistake was here
```